# Why is a static const char[] as a public class field an error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, static-members

When I add a `static const char[]` to my class as public field, the compiler gives me error, but with `static const int` it's fine. Why, and how can I fix it?

```
class example
{
public:
    static const int num2 = 5;// fine
    static const char num[] = "test";// problem
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ language does not support in-class initializers for *static* members of non-integral and non-enum types. Members of integer and enum types are given special treatment. You can give them initializer right in the class definition. All other types have to be defined outside.

This is done that way because in large percentage of cases constant integral values are used as compile-time constants, as rvalues in the program. They do not require space in the actual storage (i.e. require no physical *definition*). And at the same time the compiler can benefit greatly from knowing the value of integral constants in each translation unit (e.g. optimizations, embedding integer operands directly into machine instructions etc.) This does not apply (or applies to a much lesser degree) to non-integral types.

You have to define your static member outside of the class and provide an initializer there.

```
class example
{
public:
    static const int num2 = 5;
    static const char num[];
};

const char example::num[] = "test";
```

Just keep in mind that to obey ODR, the member definition has to be placed into one and only one implementation file. Don't try placing it into a header file.

Comment: you are not answer my question why int its fine and char[] is not

Comment: @dor_torge: That's how the language is defined. Members of integer and enum types are given special treatment. You can give them initializer right in the class definition. All other types have to be defined outside.

Comment: It can work in C++11 with the use of `constexpr`.